# ¿Como iniciar sesión en mi propio programa si perdí las claves?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, web, contraseña

Buen día.
En mi trabajo me dieron la tarea de revivir un programa que hicieron hace años con php y mysql, el problema es, que en la base de datos las claves vienen encriptadas y ya no hay ningún trabajador activo que recuerde su usuario y contraseña. He insertado por mi propia cuenta una fila con usuario y contraseña pero me sigue arrojando el mensaje de "Contraseña incorrecta".
¿Habrá alguna manera de iniciar sesión como administrador usando otra base de datos con la misma estructura? ¿O qué puedo hacer?

Comment: te sabes la contraseña del root?

Comment: ¿Por que no editas el cógido del 'login' y desactivas la validación de la contraseña?

Comment: en https://serverfault.com/questions/557710/forgot-mysql-password tiene una solucion

Comment: O comprueba que tipo de criptación usa la contraseña mirando el código (md5, sha1, etc) y agrégala o edita la del admin usando el phpmyadmin que te permite elegir entre las funciones varios cifrados cuando insertas un valor en un campo, en este caso el de la contraseña

Comment: Sí me se la clave del root.

Comment: mira mi enlaces entonces @JoséAndresRamosÁlvarez

Comment: crea un usuario y luego modifica la base de datos y darle permisos de admin...

Comment: ¿Como desactivo la validación de la contraseña?

Comment: mirate este enlace : https://www.desarrollo-web-br-bd.com/es/mysql/como-desactivo-la-validacion-de-contrasena-mysql/823499072/

Comment: ¿Esto es válido cuando el programa ya está en la web?

Comment: Pues no se que decirte amigo imagino que si aunque has copia por si acaso

Comment: Intentaré el par de acciones que me has adjuntado. @JavierG.Raya

Comment: vale amigo  :) :)

Comment: Bueno camaradas, logré acceder cambiando la clave pero esta vez aplicando un tipo de encriptación que al parecer era obligatorio, gracias al usuario @masterguru

Comment: Y también gracias al usuario @JavierG.Raya

Comment: de nada amigo :)

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya servido :-)  saludos!

Comment: gran trabajo en equipo hicimos @masterguru :-)

Comment: "yo trabajo solo" xDDDD  (es broma eh!! :-) )

Comment: okey @masterguru -:) ya lo que es broma xD